# Adjusting div blocks to be equidistant from left-right border and among themselves

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have ***n*** number of `div` blocks which must be equidistant among themselves. I am trying this but failing with `display: inline-block;`. Can someone help tell me why I am failing? The solution must not be hard-bound on pixels and should be dynamic without using hard coded widths or heights.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background: #ddf;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.sectioncontainer {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
.sec1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: pink;
}
.sec2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: orange;
}
.sec3 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectioncontainer">
  <section class="sec1">
    aaa
  </section>
  <section class="sec2">
    bbb
  </section>
  <section class="sec3">
    ccc
  </section>
</div>
```

**JS-FIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/g89d38wf/

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g89d38wf/1/)?

Comment: Or something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/g89d38wf/2/

Comment: Is it necessary to give width:32%. What if there are 4 blocks now ??? Again, I have to change he %width of sections ?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `display` of `sectioncontainer` to flex

```
.sectioncontainer {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;   
 }
```

To distribute the items in container evenly, `justify-content` as `space-between`. Check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

> The CSS `justify-content` property defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items along the main-axis of their container.

[This link](https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/#the-solutions) can help you get more insight on this.